# regex expression for XML schema

Tags: regex, xml, schema

I have this xml content, with id values from 1 to 193.

```
<member lang="en" id="UN193">
    <name>Zimbabwe</name>
    <admissionYear>1980</admissionYear>
    <population year="2019">14645468</population>
    <continent>Africa</continent>
    <officialLangInfo>
        <language script="Latin" family="Indo-European">English</language>
        <language script="Latin" family="Niger–Congo">Chewa</language>
        <language script="Latin" family="Niger–Congo">Kalanga</language>
        <otherLanguage>Chibarwe</otherLanguage>
    </officialLangInfo>
</member>
```

I created this restriction, which give me an error validation the file. Any suggestions? Many thanks.

```
    <xs:attribute name="id" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:ID">
                    <xs:pattern value="[UN][0-9]{1,3}"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
```

Comment: try `UN\d{1,3}`

Comment: UN should not be in square brackets.  They are not needed.  Square brackets would mean either U or N and you want both.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use `UN\[0-9]{1,3}` to allow ids in the range of `UN0` to `UN999`.

If you want to be more precise and only allow ids from 1 to 193, you can try something like `UN(1[0-9][0-3]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])`.

Example [here](https://regex101.com/r/fxGAPv/2).

Comment: Unless you actually want to permit non-ASCII digits, it's better to use `[0-9]` rather than `\d`. Also, you could be a bit more precise with `1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]`